# C# get derived class propertiy

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've this base class that contains list of other classes

```
public class Blacklist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

Where Card class looks like

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Cuid { get; set; }

    public int BlacklistId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have implemented a derived class that extends Blacklist class

```
public class BlacklistTwo : Blacklist
{
    public new IEnumerable<CardTwo> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

where CardTwo class extends the base Card class

The problem occurs when I try to invoke a method that accept the base class as parameter with the derived instance. The type of outer class is alright but type of cards stays implemented as base class .

Example:

```
Insert(
   new BlacklistTwo(){
     Id = 1,
     Cards = new List<CardsTwo>()
     { new CardTwo() { Id = 123123, Cuid = "123213", BlacklistId = 1}});

public void Insert(Blacklist blacklist)
{
    blacklist.GetType(); // returns BlacklistTwo
    blacklist.Cards.GetType(); // returns IEnumerable<Card> insted of IEnumerable<CardTwo>
}
```

It works when I set the parameter of method to dynamic but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: You are hiding the base property implementation using `new` keyword. So you can't access it via base class object...

Comment: Note that `BlacklistTwo` _hides_ the base `Cards` property, and then declares its own. This is not the same functionality as overriding, which it seems like you were aiming for with your `virtual` keyword.

Comment: you should not hide the member. What problem you are trying to solve by changing the type of `Card` property to `IEnumerable<CardsTwo>`? Why you can't keep using `IEnumerable<Card>`? If your provide these details, it will be easier for use to locate the root cause and possible solution.

Comment: The problem with override is that the types of Cards must match and it returns error:
Error CS1715 'BlacklistTwo.Cards': type must be 'IEnumerable<Card>' to match overridden member 'Blacklist.Card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments - you don't actually override the property since you use the 'new' keyword. I think this may be what you are trying to achive:

```
public interface ICard
{
    int CardId { get; set; }
    string Cuid { get; set; }
    int BlacklistId { get; set; }
    //.. Other methods and properties
}
public class Card : ICard
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string Cuid { get; set; }
    public int BlacklistId { get; set; }
}

public class CardTwo : ICard
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string Cuid { get; set; }
    public int BlacklistId { get; set; }
}

public class Blacklist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ICard> Cards { get; set; }
}

public class BlacklistTwo : Blacklist
{
    public override IEnumerable<ICard> Cards { get; set; }

}
```

And then:

```
public Test()
{
    ICard card1 = new Card();
    card1.CardId = 123123;
    card1.Cuid = "123213";
    card1.BlacklistId = 1;

    ICard card2 = new CardTwo();
    card2.CardId = 123123;
    card2.Cuid = "123213";
    card2.BlacklistId = 1;

    Insert(new BlacklistTwo()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Cards = new List<ICard>() { card1 ,card2 }
    });

    if (card1 is Card c1)
    {
        //Yes - this is a type of Card
    }
    
    if (card2 is CardTwo c2)
    {
        //Yes - this is a type of CardTwo
    }
}
```

You could use an interface or an abstract class, and and probably even  avoid extending the blacklist class

Comment: If I implement this approach I get that the type of Card is GeneratedType_1 where as I need the type to be CardTwo.

Comment: See updated answer. You can check the explicit type this way instead

Comment: The problem was with Mapster. Thank you for the idea of using interfaces